# Exportar csv de datos con PHP, Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

El código en HTML es :

```
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="from_date" name="from_date" aria-describedby="basic-addon3">
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="to_date"    name="to_date" aria-describedby="basic-addon3">
    </div>

    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary input-group mb-3 margin" name="buscar" id="buscar" value="Buscar"/>

<input type="button" class="btn btn-success mb-3 margin" name="export" id ="export" value="Export CSV"/>
```

Tengo el siguiente Script que me devuelve los datos de la base de datos:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
  var date_input=$('input[name="from_date"]'); 
  var options={
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    todayHighlight: true,
    autoclose: true,
  };
  date_input.datepicker(options);
  var date_input=$('input[name="to_date"]');
  var options={
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    todayHighlight: true,
    autoclose: true,
  };
  date_input.datepicker(options);

      $('#buscar').click(function(){
        var from_date = $('#from_date').val();
        var to_date = $('#to_date').val();
        var numero_serie = $('#numero_serie').val();
      if(from_date != '' && to_date != '')
      {

        $.ajax({
          url:'process.php',
          method:"POST",
          data:{from_date:from_date, to_date:to_date, numero_serie:numero_serie},
           success:function(data)
          {

            $('#datos').html(data);
          }
        });
      }
      else
      {
        alert("Selecciona una fecha");
      }
});
      $('#export').click(function(){
        $.post("export.php"),{
        var from_date = $('#from_date').val();
        var to_date = $('#to_date').val();
        var numero_serie = $('#numero_serie').val();}

});
}); 
</script>
```

El archivo export.php es:

```
if(isset($_POST["from_date"],$_POST["to_date"],$_POST["numero_serie"]))
{
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost:3306","usuario","password","bd");
$filename = date('Ymd').'-'.$_POST["numero_serie"].'.csv';
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
$output = fopen('php://output','w');
fputcsv($output, array('Fecha', 'Hora', 'WA', 'Estado', 'Numero_serie'));

$query="SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE fecha_reg BETWEEN '".$_POST["from_date"]."' AND '".$_POST["to_date"]."' AND numero_serie = '".$_POST["numero_serie"]."'";

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    fputcsv($output, $row, ";");
}
fclose($output);
exit;
}

?>
```

Me funciona correctamente la búsqueda por fechas de los registros mediante ajax, pero quiero exportarlos a CSV, ¿Cómo paso los parámetros con $('#export').click(function(){ a export.php para que me aparezca la ventana de dialogo de guardar archivo?, he leído que con ajax no es la forma correcta de hacerlo.

¿Cuál sería la forma correcta de realizar esto?

Gracias.

Comment: Si, $.post("export.php"),{... aún no está terminado ahí es dónde debería enviar los parámetros a export.php que procesa los datos con un select y mediante fputcsv() genero el csv.

Comment: Si, pero mi pregunta es ¿la respuesta del mismo sería un `link` al archivo? ¿El nombre del archivo cambiaría en cada llamada?

Comment: No tendría que devolver nada sino una ventana de guardar el archivo csv con los datos seleccionados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal como dices la forma correcta de hacer la descarga no sería a través de un ajax, tienes que redirigir a la función en php que va a encargarse de la descarga del documento:

```
$('#export').click(function(){
    var from_date    = $('#from_date').val();
    var to_date      = $('#to_date').val();
    var numero_serie = $('#numero_serie').val();

    document.location.href = 'export.php'+
                             '?from_date='+JSON.stringify(from_date)+
                             '&to_date='+JSON.stringify(to_date)+
                             '&numero_serie='+numero_serie;
});
```

El código en PHP te quedaría mas o menos así:

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_GET["from_date"],$_GET["to_date"],$_GET["numero_serie"])) {

        $from_date  = json_decode($_GET["from_date"]);
        $to_date        = json_decode($_GET["to_date"]);
        $numero_serie   = $_GET["numero_serie"];

        $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost:3306","usuario","password","bd");
        $query="SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE fecha_reg BETWEEN '".$from_date."' AND '".$to_date."' AND numero_serie = '".$numero_serie."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

        $output = fopen('php://output','w');
        fputcsv($output, array('Fecha', 'Hora', 'WA', 'Estado', 'Numero_serie'));

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            fputcsv($output, $row, ";");

        fclose($output);
        $filename = date('Ymd').'-'.$numero_serie.'.csv';
        header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
        print($output);
    }
?>
```

Coméntame si te funciona.
Según mi propia experiencia el nombre del archivo no debe tener demasiados caracteres ya que puede que no se te descargue.

Comment: Gracias, Gonsabb por tu respuesta, te comento que al aplicar la función que has propuesto me devuelve el resultado como texto en la pantalla, pero no me aparece el cuadro de dialogo para guardar el csv.

Comment: Se te debería de descargar automáticamente, sin embargo, ¿te lo está pintando por pantalla? Dejame hacer algunas pruebas más y ahora te digo.

Comment: Si por pantalla me lo está pintando, fijate en la respuesta que acabo de añadir así me está funcionando, pero no sé si es la mejor forma de hacerlo.

Answer (score 0):

De momento lo que necesito me está funcionando de esta manera;

```
 $('#export').click(function(){
    $.post("export.php"),{
    var from_date = $('#from_date').val();
    var to_date = $('#to_date').val();
    var numero_serie = $('#numero_serie').val()  
 $.ajax({
          url:'export.php',
          method:"POST",
          data:{from_date:from_date, to_date:to_date,  numero_serie:numero_serie},
           success:function(data)
          {
            var filename = numero_serie+'_'+from_date+'_'+to_date+'.csv';
            var uri = 'data:application/csv;charset=UTF-8,' + encodeURIComponent(data);
            var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
            downloadLink.href = uri;
            downloadLink.download = filename;

            document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
            downloadLink.click();
            document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
          }
            });
;}
```

Comment: Si funciona no hay problema, esa forma puede ser tan correcta como cualquier otra, en mi caso normalmente lo hago sin llamada ajax, sino llamando directamente a la función pasando los parametros por url, pero entiendo que cada maestro tiene su librillo.

Comment: Funcionar funciona, pero he leído que no es la forma más adecuada mediante ajax, si encuentras otra alternativa más eficaz, la utilizaré.

Comment: Igualmente te recomendaría no usar el *charset=UTF-8* para el archivo, ya que los csv no guardan la codificación de caracteres

Comment: Ok, gracias por tu ayuda ;)